# Simplify $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}3^{n-i}$

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

This summation where $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$a(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}3^{n-i}$

...gives rise to this sequence for $a(n)$:

1,5,19,65,211...

...which is OEIS [A001047](https://oeis.org/A001047).

The OEIS entry has the formula as $a(n)=3^n-2^n$.

My question is how to derive $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}3^{n-i}=3^n-2^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}3^{n-i} = \frac{3^n}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{2}{3})^i = \frac{3^n}{2} \frac{2}{3}\frac{1-(\frac{2}{3})^n}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3} \frac{3^n-2^n}{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{3} (3^n-2^n) = 3^n -2^n$$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* write it as
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n
 3^n 2^{-1} (2/3)^i
$$
and calculate the geometric sum

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$(3-2)\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}3^{n-i}=\sum_{i=1}^n(2^{i-1}3^{n-i+1}-2^{i} 3^{n-i})$$ and the sum collapses to $3^n-2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n2^{i-1}3^{n-i}=\frac{3^n}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^i,$$
and you should recognize this last famous sum.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, based on the generalized case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404858/168053). This does not require full expansion of the original summation.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}3^{n-i}
&=\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}(1+2)^{n-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\binom {n-i}j2^j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\binom {n-i}j2^{i+j-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=i-1}^{n-1}\binom {n-i}{i-i+1}2^k
&&(k=i+j-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=i}^{n}\binom {n-i}{k-i}2^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k \binom {n-i}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} \sum_{r=n-k}^{n-1}\binom r{n-k}
&&(r=n-i)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k-1}\binom n{n-k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}\binom n{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom nk 2^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k-2^n\\
&=\color{red}{3^n-2^n}
\end{align}$$