# Difference of $n$-th power of two consecutive integers

Tags: summation

This question came about after reading this other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401192/simplify-sum-i-1n-2i-13n-i).

> Show that
>   $$\sum_{r=1}^n a^{r-1}\left[\binom n{r-1}-(a+1)^{n-r}\right]=0$$
>   **without** expanding the summation in full.

If we expand the summation in full we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n \binom n{r-1}a^{r-1}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom nr a^r\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr a^r-a^n\\
&=(a+1)^n-a^n\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n (a+1)^{n-r}a^{r-1}
&=\frac {(a+1)^n}a\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac a{a+1}\right)^r\\
&=\frac {(a+1)^n}a\cdot \frac a{a+1}\cdot\frac {1-\left(\frac a{a+1}\right)^n}{1-\frac a{a+1}}\\
&=(a+1)^n-a^n\end{align}$$
which are equal to each other.

Comment: Can you come up with a combinatorial interpretation of the above fact? At least I am thinking of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Having given it further thought, here's one approach:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n a^{r-1}(a+1)^{n-r}
&=\sum_{r=1}^na^{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\binom {n-r}ja^j\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\binom {n-r}ja^{r+j-1}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{k=r-1}^{n-1}\binom {n-r}{k+1-r}a^k
&&(k=r+j-1)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{k=r}^n\binom {n-r}{k-r}a^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}\sum_{r=1}^k\binom {n-r}{k-r}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}\sum_{r=1}^k\binom {n-r}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}\sum_{s=n-k}^{n-1}\binom s{n-k}
&&(s=n-r)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}\binom n{n-k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}\binom n{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n a^{r-1}\binom n{r-1}\\
\sum_{r=1}^n a^{r-1}\left[\binom n{r-1}-(a+1)^{n-r}\right]&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Looks like some of my answers - a lot of algebra and then it miraculously works out. Congratulations.

Comment: @martycohen - Thank you! Yes, very nice when it all falls into place.